# Idiomatic way of representing generic data type in golang

Tags: go

In a particular implementation of AST, I have a `node` which is an interface and `ExprNode`, `EvalNode` and some leaf nodes. Now leaf nodes can be string node or number node or function node
Each expression node can have only two leaf nodes. One on left and One on right.

```golang
type Node interface{
  Pos() int64
  Typ() NodeType 
}

type StringNode struct{
  Pos int64
  Val string
  Node
}

type NumberNode struct {
  Pos int64
  Val float64
  Node
}

type ExprNode struct {
  Lhs  ???  //should accept either StringNode or NumberNode 
  Op   Operation
  Rhs  ???  //should accept either StringNode or NumberNode 
  Node
}

type EvalNode struct{
  Lhs     *ExprNode
  AllFlag bool
  Rhs     *ExprNode
  Node
}
```

I've come up with a workaround which may not be idiomatic. I'm looking if there's any better way of doing this

```golang
type LeafNode interface{
  IsLeaf() bool
}

func (n *StringNode) IsLeaf() bool{
  return true
}

func (n *NumberNode) IsLeaf() bool{
  return true
}

type ExprNode struct {
  Lhs  LeafNode   //workaround
  Op   Operation
  Rhs  LeafNode   //workaround
  Node
}
```

Now in the above workaround, IsLeaf() function is of no significance for me, but I had to use it to limit the node types accepted on ExprNode.

Sincere apologies if the title looked too broad.

Question: Is there a better way of programming the above scenario.

Note: I'm only looking for idiomatic ways of handling above scenario and not for alternate implementations of the algorithm.

Comment: To use an interface in this case looks idiomatic to me.  But the interface itself is not perfect. I do not understand why `Lhs` and `Rhs` are not a `Node` type. Later you can use a type assertion or type switch to get the types back.

Comment: I would be looking for some real functionality common to leaf nodes; if there is none, there seems to be minimal benefit in trying to establish a dedicated type/interface for them.

Comment: @Adrian Think of this way: dedicated type not for sharing same traits (functions) but for sharing similar attributes (fields). Like a type that can be generic among group of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following types to ensure that only leaf types can be assigned to ExprNode.Lhs and Exprnode.Rhs:

```
type Node interface{
  Pos() int64
  Typ() NodeType 
}

type LeafNode interface {
  Node
  Leaf() // sentinel function to distinguish leaf types from other types
}

func (*NumberNode) Leaf() {}
func (*StringNode) Leaf() {}

type ExprNode struct {
  Lhs  LeafNode 
  Op   Operation
  Rhs  LeafNode 
  Node
}
```